# I want to use ngmodel and ngforms in my angular custom element

Tags: angular, angular8, web-component, custom-element

I created an angular component with two input fields which contains ngModel. Now I am converting the component to custom element using createcustomelement api in angular.

But after converting, I couldn't able to use the angular features like ngmodel.

The JSP page which having this custom element gives the following error while rendering:

"e.getDOM of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Angular Reactive Forms works with an abstraction model called `ControlValueAccessor`. It’s a common interface that allow Angular to work with any kind of control value.

Here is the default one: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts

And here is an example of implementation with the Material Web Component Textfield:

```js
import { Directive, forwardRef, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

import { TextField as MWCTextField } from '@material/mwc-textfield';

export const MWC_TEXTFIELD_VALUE_ACCESSOR = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => MWCTextFieldValueAccessorDirective),
    multi: true,
};

@Directive({
    // eslint-disable-next-line @angular-eslint/directive-selector
    selector: 'mwc-textfield[ngModel],mwc-textfield[formControl],mwc-textfield[formControlName]',
    providers: [MWC_TEXTFIELD_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
})
export class MWCTextFieldValueAccessorDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {
    public onChange?: (val: string) => void;
    public onTouched?: () => void;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef<MWCTextField>) { }

    @HostListener('change')
    public onFieldChange(): void {
        this.onChange?.(this.elementRef.nativeElement.value);
    }

    @HostListener('blur')
    public onFieldBlur(): void {
        this.onTouched?.();
    }

    public writeValue(value: string): void {
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = value;
    }

    public registerOnChange(fn: (val: string) => void): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    public registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }
}
```